# Функция вычисления площади

Tags: javascript

[image: а]

Есть такая задачка. В js я начинающий и вижу такое решение:

```
var s =  a * h / 0.5
```

Правильно ли? В задании вообще сказано "функция", а в моем решении ее нет.
Подскажите

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поместите Ваш код внутрь функции:

```js
function areaOfTriangle(base, height) {
  return 0.5 * base * height;
}

var a = 22;
var h = 33;
var s = areaOfTriangle(a, h);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Как будет выглядеть конечная версия?

Comment: @RafaelShepard Как в ответе.

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @RafaelShepard На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с предыдущим участником, только, я считаю, не нужно лишнее переменные создавать.

```js
function areaOfTriangle(base, height) {
  return 0.5 * base * height;
}

var s = areaOfTriangle(22, 33);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Ответ, по-сути, ничем не отличается от предыдущего. С таким же успехом вы могли бы просто поменять имя функции.

Comment: а можно еще создать объект треугольника и доставать значения из него, суть решения от этого не меняется от слова совсем т.к. это просто пример использования